# How can I get a list of all pull requests for a repo through the github API?

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request

I want to obtain a list of all pull requests on a repo through the github API.

I've followed the instructions at http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/ but when I query `/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls` it's consistently returning fewer pull requests than displayed on the website.

For example, when I query the `torvalds/linux` repo I get 9 open pull requests (there are 14 on the website). If I add `?state=closed` I get a different set of 11 closed pull requests (the website shows around 20).

Does anyone know where this discrepancy arises, and if there's any way to get a complete list of pull requests for a repo through the API?

Comment: Can you check again? Did a test, expected 19, got 19

Answer (score 41):

You can get all pull requests (closed, opened, merged) through the variable `state`.

Just set `state=all` in the GET query, like this->

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls?state=all
```

For more info: check the Parameters table at  https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests

Edit: As per Tomáš Votruba's comment:

> the default value for, "per_page=30". The maximum is per_page=100. To get more than 100 results, you need to call it multiple itmes: "&page=1", "&page=2"...

Comment: how to filter out only the pull request number from the results obtained

Comment: My problem is that if I GET ?state=all, it gives a smaller number than ?state=closed + ?state=open

Comment: Important: the default value for, "per_page=30". The maximum is per_page=100. To get more than 100 results, you need to call it multiple itmes: "&page=1", "&page=2"...

Comment: How do we know that there are more pages? It does not seem that there is any response attribute

Comment: How about private repositories?

Comment: what about just filter for an exact pull request number ?

Answer (score 17):

PyGithub (https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub), a Python library to access the GitHub API v3, enables you to get paginated resources.

For example,

```
g = Github(login_or_token=$YOUR_TOKEN, per_page=100)
r = g.get_repo($REPO_NUMBER)

for pull in r.get_pulls('all'):
    # You can access pulls
```

See the documentation (http://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 11):

With Github's new official [CLI](https://cli.github.com/) (command line interface):

```
gh pr list --repo OWNER/REPO
```

which would produce something like:

```
Showing 2 of 2 pull requests in OWNER/REPO

#62  Doing something    that-weird-branch-name
#58  My PR title        wasnt-inspired-branch
```

See additional [details and options](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list) and [installation instructions](https://cli.github.com/manual/installation).

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to get a complete list and you're doing it. What are you using to communicate with the API? I suspect you may not be doing something correctly. For example (there are only 13 open pull requests currently) using my API wrapper (github3.py) I get all of the open pull requests. An example of how to do it without my wrapper in python is:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/pulls')
len(r.json()) == 13
```

and I can also get that result (vaguely) in cURL by counting the results myself: `curl https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/pulls`.

If you, however, run into a repository with more than 25 (or 30) pull requests that's an entirely different issue but most certainly it is not what you're encountering now.

Comment: Is there a way to get more than 30 pull requests for a repo? Maybe in different network requests?

Comment: @shreyj many endpoints on the GitHub API are paginated and can be accessed using the [Link headers](http://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination) on the response. If you're trying to use python or ruby to make the request, I can certainly help you more with that.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) to request all pull requests for a repo. It requests all the pull requests by default if you don't specify the `states` field :

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "material-ui", owner: "mui-org") {
    pullRequests(first: 100, orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC}) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        title
        state
        author {
          login
        }
        createdAt
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository%28name%3A%20%22material-ui%22%2C%20owner%3A%20%22mui-org%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pullRequests%28first%3A%20100%2C%20orderBy%3A%20%7Bfield%3A%20CREATED_AT%2C%20direction%3A%20DESC%7D%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20state%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20author%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20login%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Answer (score 3):

1. If you want to retrieve all pull requests (commits, comments, issues etc) you have to use pagination. 
   https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination
2. The GET request "pulls" will only return open pull-requests.
3. If you want to get all pull-requests either you do set the parameter state to all, or you use issues.

**Extra information**

If you need other data from Github, such as issues, then you can identify pull-requests from issues, and you can then retrieve each pull-request no matter if it is closed or open. It will also give you a couple of more attributes (mergeable, merged, merge-commit-sha, nr of commits etc)
If an issue is a pull-request, then it will contain that attribute. Otherwise, it is just an issue.

**From the API:** https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#labels-assignees-and-milestones

"Every pull request is an issue, but not every issue is a pull request. For this reason, “shared” actions for both features, like manipulating assignees, labels and milestones, are provided within the Issues API."

**Edit** I just found that issues behaves similar to pull-requests, so one would need to do retrieve all by setting the state parameter to all

Comment: can you please provide the code for getting all the pull request( witht the state `all`)

Comment: pardon me for asking, I just see it is provided by @akshaynagpal

Answer (score 1):

The search API shoul help: https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.2/user/articles/searching-issues/

q = repo:org/name is:pr ...

Answer (score 1):

GitHub provides a "Link" header which specifies the previous, next and last URL to fetch the values.Eg, Link Header response,
`<https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls?state=all&page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls?state=all&page=15>; rel="last"`
*rel="next"* suggests the next set of values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of Python code that retrieves information of all pull requests from a specific GitHub repository and parses it into a nice DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

organization = 'pvlib'
repository = 'pvlib-python'
state = 'all'  # other options include 'closed' or 'open'

page = 1  # initialize page number to 1 (first page)
dfs = []  # create empty list to hold individual dataframes
# Note it is necessary to loop as each request retrieves maximum 30 entries
while True:
    url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{organization}/{repository}/pulls?" \
        f"state={state}&page={page}"
    dfi = pd.read_json(url)
    if dfi.empty:
        break
    dfs.append(dfi)  # add dataframe to list of dataframes
    page += 1  # Advance onto the next page

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis='rows', ignore_index=True)

# Create a new column with usernames
df['username'] = pd.json_normalize(df['user'])['login']
```